# How to retrieve multiples variables separately with pythontex?

Tags: pythontex

### Edit

I found something, but not working as I would like under Ti*k*Z. Here is the code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
from  math import *
def calculus(xa,ya,xb,yb):
    d=round(sqrt((xb-xa)**2+(yb-ya)**2),3)
    xk=(xa+xb)/2
    yk=(ya+yb)/2
    return d,xk,yk
\end{pycode}


With \textbackslash{}py\{calculus(0,0,1,1)\} the result is \py{calculus(0,0,1,1)}

With \textbackslash{}py\{calculus(0,0,1,1)[0]\} the result is \py{calculus(0,0,1,1)[0]}

With \textbackslash{}py\{calculus(0,0,1,1)[1]\} the result is \py{calculus(0,0,1,1)[1]}

With \textbackslash{}py\{calculus(0,0,1,1)[2]\} the result is \py{calculus(0,0,1,1)[2]}

\begin{center}
\def\xa{0}
\def\ya{0}
\def\xb{1}
\def\yb{1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
    \draw (\xa,\ya) node [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} node [left] {$A$} -- (\xb,\yb) node [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} node [right] {$B$};
    \draw ({(\xa+\xb)/2},{(\ya+\yb)/2}) node [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} node [below right] {$K$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Inside the tikz block, I would like to replace :

```
\draw ({(\xa+\xb)/2},{(\ya+\yb)/2}) node [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} node [below right] {$K$};
```

with something like :

```
\draw ({\py{calculus(\xa,\ya,\xb,\yb)[1]}},{\py{calculus(\xa,\ya,\xb,\xb)[2]}})  node [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} node [above] {$K$};
```

---

### Original post

I would like to retrieve multiple variables separatly after using pythontex. I know how to retrieve a single variable, and multiples variables at the same time, but not separatly. Here is an example :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\begin{document}

\begin{pycode}
def sum1(x,y):
    z=x+y
    return z
\end{pycode}

With sum1 the result is \py{sum1(2,3)}

\begin{pycode}
def sum2(x,y):
    z=x+y
    return x,y,z
\end{pycode}

With sum2 the result is \py{sum2(2,3)}

\end{document}
```

and the output is :

[image]

What I want to do is to use x, y and z variables returned by python code, to write for example :

The result of 2 + 3 = 5.

And I want to know if it's possible to do that outside the python code.

Thanks

Comment: When mixing pythontex and tikz, the `pusyb` environment can be useful, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65294/10742

Comment: yes I saw it yesterday, but with \draw (!{\py{calculus(\xa,\ya,\xb,\yb)[1]}},!{\py{calculus(\xa,\ya,\xb,\yb)[1]}}) node  [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} ; the compilation doesn't stop.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that `\def\xa{0}` LaTeX statements can be used in combination with `pythontex`. If you change those statements (starting at your `center` environment) to `\pyc{xa=0}` statements, then you can use the `pysub` environment as @GPoore suggests.

Here's your code, modified:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

    \begin{pycode}
from  math import *
def calculus(xa,ya,xb,yb):
    d=round(sqrt((xb-xa)**2+(yb-ya)**2),3)
    xk=(xa+xb)/2
    yk=(ya+yb)/2
    return d,xk,yk
\end{pycode}


With \textbackslash{}py\{calculus(0,0,1,1)\} the result is \py{calculus(0,0,1,1)}

With \textbackslash{}py\{calculus(0,0,1,1)[0]\} the result is \py{calculus(0,0,1,1)[0]}

With \textbackslash{}py\{calculus(0,0,1,1)[1]\} the result is \py{calculus(0,0,1,1)[1]}

With \textbackslash{}py\{calculus(0,0,1,1)[2]\} the result is \py{calculus(0,0,1,1)[2]}

\begin{center}
    \pyc{xa=0}
    \pyc{ya=0}
    \pyc{xb=1}
    \pyc{yb=1}
\begin{pysub}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm, scale=1, every node/.style={scale=1}]
    \draw (!{xa},!{ya}) node [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} node [left] {$A$} -- (!{xb},!{yb}) node [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} node [right] {$B$};

    \draw (!{calculus(xa,ya,xb,yb)[1]},!{calculus(xa,ya,xb,xb)[2]})  node [circle,inner sep=1pt,fill] {} node [above] {$K$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pysub}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```